# Array to string conversion and Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

I am not experienced with php(i am new).

i am trying to use this code http://mach13.com/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-php to find the name of a variable, but I keep getting:

Array to string conversion for the line :

```
$aDiffKeys = array_keys (array_diff_assoc ($aDefinedVars_0, $aDefinedVars));
```

and also i get "only variables should be passed by reference" when I use

```
var_name($a, get_defined_vars());
```

How can I make those messages disappear? Because the entire code is working(I get the desired output).

Here is the code

```
<?php
function var_name (&$iVar, &$aDefinedVars)
{
foreach ($aDefinedVars as $k=>$v)
    $aDefinedVars_0[$k] = $v;

$iVarSave = $iVar;
$iVar     =!$iVar;

$aDiffKeys = array_keys (array_diff_assoc ($aDefinedVars_0, $aDefinedVars));
$iVar      = $iVarSave;

return $aDiffKeys[0];
}
$a=12;
echo var_name($a,get_defined_vars());
//ini_set('display_errors', '0');
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Make sure you're using correct types. Even if PHP sometimes can cast types of variables, it is a bad practice to operate such way.

Comment: I have no idea where you would need this to begin with. If you can type `var_name($a)`, *you already know the variable name: "a"!*

Comment: well i get the variable name as string!

Comment: *well i get the variable name as string!* -- that's what the function does? What **exactly** are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Actually the easiest way to get the var name AS A STRING is $var_name = eval('substr(\'$var\', 1);');

Comment: yes...I searched another way to do it, but couldn't find one..

Comment: Please tell us what you intend to use this for. Especially since you're new to PHP: stop pursuing this avenue, it makes no sense. There's a better solution for whatever problem you're trying to solve with this; but we cannot help you with your real problem if you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: I want to get a variable's name in a string...so if i have the variable $random , the result of the function will be 'random'(stored as a string). That is all I want.

Comment: And again: **why do you want this?!** What is the larger purpose to find the variable name? What are you going to do with it once you found it?

Comment: Let's say that i only want this! How do i do it? I only want the variable name. I don't like to tell the others my very long story on what i want to do with it, because i think of resolving the problem(not finding the name, the rest of it) in one way, and if i will tell you what i want to do with it, you will come with your ideea, wich will be different from mine, and will disturb my entire plan (wich is not 50 lines of code). So again, my only problem is how to store the var name, not the rest.I don't want you to help me with my entire project,i only want you to help me with the problem above

Comment: Alright, suit yourself. Just saying that it seems to me like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/476), since it's not really possible to do this in PHP without really nasty hacks (if at all), and that any code requiring these nasty hacks is probably on the wrong track. Very complex applications have been written in PHP without the need to find the name of a variable you already have.

Answer (score 9):

The Array to String conversion notice started in PHP v5.4.0.  Since `array_diff_assoc()` doesn't search recursively, it is notifying you that it found that one of the values in your array is also an array and it had to convert it to a string.

Here's an example on how to use `array_diff_assoc()` for a multi-dimensional array... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php#73972

Or perhaps switching out `array_diff_assoc()` for `array_diff_key()` would work for your purpose if you are only comparing the keys?

Comment: +1 for usefull link. But see the solution rigth below that one: [link](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php#111675)

Comment: Please note that the code on that link has strict match whilst the whole php rainbowland has ==. If you swap over the array_diff_assoc() to the array_diff_assoc_recursive() please watch out the check.

Answer (score 1):

> only variables should be passed by reference

You are passing the result of a function call as an argument. You aren't passing a variable.

```
$vars = get_defined_vars();
echo var_name($a,$vars);
```

Also, unless you're intentionally modifying one of the variables you shouldn't be passing it as a reference. That way any changes made are local to the function.

Comment: it does not work in my case, i get Undefined offset: 0, which means it didn't find my var name...and i also still get  Array to string conversion