# Array to string conversion when comparing arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use a php inbuilt function to compare 2 arrays.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("new.json"), true);
$last_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("last.json"), true);
$difference = array_diff_assoc($json, $last_json);
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /storage/whitelist_update.php on line 10

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a couple more lines around line 10, your issue isn't here... since you're not converting an array to a string.

Comment: Line 10 is the $difference = array_diff_assoc() function.

Comment: btw: you most likely meant `conversion`, not `conversation` I assume..

Comment: https://gyazo.com/bef683da4db1afa49ec17bfbf28f09d7

Comment: The issue is *NOT* on your `array_diff_assoc` line!  Look at your code again, there is a `require_once` line.  What does is, basically copy & paste that file into the current line.  So line 10 is *actually* a line inside the included file.

Comment: @RocketHazmat No. Luckily this is not the php behavior.

Comment: @Rizier123 in what sense is this question a duplicate of the one you linked (or did not specify, I don't quite understand)?

Comment: @fusion3k: Am I wrong in my comment?

Comment: "Array to string conversion" means somewhere, you are using a variable in a ***string*** context, but that variable is actually an array.  For example: `$a = [];  echo $a;`  The variable is "converted" to a string, but actually all you get is the string `"Array"`.  See: https://eval.in/566676

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yup. If the error is in included/required file, its path is in the error notice.

Comment: @fusion3k: I tested this and... turns our you're right!  I still think the error is in that file though since "Array to string conversion" makes no sense for `array_diff_assoc`.

Comment: It seems that the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253885/array-to-string-conversion-and-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference

Comment: @WalterTross: That looks like it would explain it!  Good job.  You should post that as an answer (or close as a dupe).

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have already invested too much time... Go ahead if you want

Comment: @RocketHazmat This error would happen if the array is 2-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! The issue was that the file couldn't read "last.json" but when I changed that to its entire link it seems to work. Thanks guys! :D